# jQuery scrollTo

Tags: jquery, html, scrollto

i have this table inside an div with specified width that has horizontal scroll.

```
<div id="content">
<table class="tbclass">
<tr>
    <th>h1</th>
    <th>h2</th>
    <th>h3</th>
    <th>h4</th>
    <th>h5</th>
    <th>h6</th>
    <th>h7</th>
    <th>h8</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="inputname1" id="inputid1" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="inputname2" id="inputid2" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="inputname3" id="inputid3" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="inputname4" id="inputid4" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="inputname5" id="inputid5" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="inputname6" id="inputid6" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="inputname7" id="inputid7" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="inputname8" id="inputid8" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

after page is loaded i want to scroll to a specific input by example `input id="inputid4"` using jquery. i look over scrollto implemented in jquery but there are the example using the index of the element and i don't know how to use it with a specific id instead of index.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the scrollTo plugin

http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/

Is the `div` or `table` scrollable? Try something like:

```
$('#content').scrollTo($("#inputid4"));
```

or

```
$('.tbclass').scrollTo($("#inputid4"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Or, get the index of the element and pass it to scrollTo

```
$("#content").scrollTo($("#inputid4").index());
```